# passing multiple php variables into function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

**Set-up**

Several WooCommerce webshops on one Wordpress multisite installation, meaning one functions.php file in which custom functions for all webshops can be added.

Below the product price on each product page, a dynamic text line is displayed given certain conditions hold; e.g. given product price, compute and display the product's monthly payment price if a customer chooses to order via spread payment.

The webshops are country-specific thus each has its own language.

---

**Issue**

I'm familiar with Python, not with PhP.

Dependent on the website's language, a text string in that language needs to be displayed.

E.g. *Spread payment from...* if the website is in English and *Gespreid betalen vanaf...* if in Dutch.

I created a function – `set_language_grenke_text()` – to check the domain name country code and then create the variables for the string text.

Additionally, I created `grenke_text()` to compute the monthly price based on the product price and display the text line on the product page given certain conditions regarding the product price hold.

`grenke_text()` needs to use the variables created in `set_language_grenke_text()`, but isn't doing this and I'm not sure where to declare global variables and where not. Or if that is the issue at all.

---

**Code**

```
function set_language_grenke_text() {
    global $spread_pay_text_start;      
    global $spread_pay_text_end;    
    global $slug;               

    // check if german or dutch website // 
    if (strpos($domain, '.nl') !== false) {             

        // define spread payment text // 
        $spread_pay_text_start = 'Bedrijfsmatig leasen vanaf ';
        $spread_pay_text_end = ' p/m';

        // spread payment page info slug
        $slug = '/leasen-via-grenke/';  

    } else if (strpos($domain, '.de') !== false) {              

        // define spread payment text // 
        $spread_pay_text_start = 'Business-Leasing von ';
        $spread_pay_text_end = ' p/m';

        // spread payment page info slug
        $slug = '/leasing-ueber-grenke/';   
    }
}

//add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );
// insert Grenke leasing on product page for products from €500 excl. VAT
function grenke_text() {
    global $product;    
    global $spread_pay_text_start;      
    global $spread_pay_text_end;    
    global $slug;          

    // set minimum and maximum product price for Grenke
    $min_amount = 500;

    // set minimum and maximum payment period for Grenke
    $min_period = 15;
    $max_period = 60;       

    // set Grenke factor for 60 months for up to €2.500 (2019)
    $factor = 2.51;

    // check if product exists //
    if ($product) {                                 

        // get product price //    
        $product_price =  $product->get_price();
        // compute PartPay product spread price // 
        $product_price_spread = number_format($product_price / 100 * $factor, 2, ',', '.');
        // get shop's currency //       
        $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

        // define echo line
        $start_echo = "<u><div class=\"spread_payment\"><a href=\"https://";
        $middle_echo = "<strong style=\"display: inline\"><font color=\"#931914\">";
        $finish_echo = "</strong></font></a></div></u>";

        // get domain
        $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];      

        // define spread payment text //        
        $spread_payment_text = $start_echo.$domain.$slug."\">".$spread_pay_text_start.$middle_echo.$currency.$product_price_spread.$spread_pay_text_end.$finish_echo;

        // echo the spread_payment_text if conditions hold // 
        if ($product_price >= $min_amount) {
            echo $spread_payment_text;
            }       
        }    
}

// define shortcode for function
add_action( 'grenke_text', 'grenke_text', 10 );
```

How do I correctly get the variables defined in `set_language_grenke_text()` in `grenke_text()`?

Comment: Refer to the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php. Global variables should be avoided most of the time.

Comment: @LucSpan you've defined a function `set_language_grenke_text()` but where are you using it? the variables defined in this function would not contains anything until the function get called.

Comment: @skndrkhtr5 ah... feeling stupid now. I didn't call it. How do I call it such that the variables are usable? Feeling stupid 2x time.

Comment: @LucSpan you may call it directly after your function like this `set_language_grenke_text();` or if you want to work this on initialization of wp then use the hook below the function like this
`add_action( 'init', 'set_language_grenke_text' );`

Comment: @LucSpan see my answer

Comment: @LucSpan also `add_shortcode` function will be used to generate shortcode. I thought you might need this :)

Answer (score 0):

Call your function like this

```
function set_language_grenke_text() {
    global $spread_pay_text_start;      
    global $spread_pay_text_end;    
    global $slug;               

    // check if german or dutch website // 
    if (strpos($domain, '.nl') !== false) {             

        // define spread payment text // 
        $spread_pay_text_start = 'Bedrijfsmatig leasen vanaf ';
        $spread_pay_text_end = ' p/m';

        // spread payment page info slug
        $slug = '/leasen-via-grenke/';  

    } else if (strpos($domain, '.de') !== false) {              

        // define spread payment text // 
        $spread_pay_text_start = 'Business-Leasing von ';
        $spread_pay_text_end = ' p/m';

        // spread payment page info slug
        $slug = '/leasing-ueber-grenke/';   
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'set_language_grenke_text' );
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but this doesn't do anything.